# Looking for an AC current sensor for less than 10A measurements

Tags: current, sensor, measurement, system

We are building a voltage and current acquisition system using NI hardware. While voltage measurements are done directly using the NI IO Module, current measurements need a sensor. We have a 100A (ydhc 013-000) sensor with a linearity between 10% and 120% of rated current (100A). But since we are aiming to install the system in households, low current consumption should be taken into consideration and this sensor don't seem to be convenient.

Can you please give me some suggestions for more convenient ones?

Comment: A shunt resistor?

Comment: In households with NI hardware? Bill Gates house, maybe. Look at LEM sensors.

Comment: Current transformer should be the obvious choice?

Comment: In the industry they abbreviate it CT (current transformer). There are types which can snap on over the wire, and types which require the wire to be threaded through the hole.

Comment: Using a Shunt resistor wouldn't be practical in a household for many reasons.
We do have a CT but as I said, it doesn't give correct measurements under 10A.

Comment: I am sure there are other CT's available. Or you can change the resistor, maybe.

Comment: What is the highest current you need to sense? Do you need to sense up to 100A?

Comment: not really 30A is enough. Maybe switching between 30A CT and 10A CT would solve the problem.
Thank you for your time and consideration :)

Comment: If you need a wide-band very accurate CT call Pearson Electronics in California. For $600 they have a CT good for 100mA to 50 Amps at -3 dB at 1 MHZ. 50 ohm output to a BNC connector. You can expect to pay dearly for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YDHC 013-000 seems more than appropriate for your application, it is used in the [Open Energy Monitor](https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/yhdc-ct-sensor-report) and well documented.

Since in home use you are talking about it being positioned potentially in branch circuits, you could simply pass the wire through the sensor twice to get 50 A full scale or three times to get 33 A full scale.

More details, especially concerning the Burden resistor is shown [here](https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/files/Yhdc_CT_Report_(Iss_6).pdf).

Comment: Or choose a burden R between 18 and 120 ohms and get latest version

Comment: That exact sensor doesn't output correct values if load uses less than 10A. right? so in cases when no appliance is working, (idealy 0A is passing through the wire) then current sensor is not appropriate, no?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75. I do not recommend increasing the burden to 120 Ohms. This introduces both current and phase problems.

Comment: @MedAymaneAhajjam ...the sensor is appropriate, at zero current you will get 0 V output. The device is reasonably linear down to well less than 10% of full scale.

Comment: Yes. I guess it's okay then! Thanks for all your replies!